# Swiper Js autoplay после окончания видео

Tags: javascript, swiper

Не смог найти ответ на вопрос. Делаю слайды, где, в том числе, есть и видео, и картинки. Ставлю свойство autoplay. Все файлы видео и картинок лежат локально. Как заставить переключать на следующий слайд только после завершения видео, а не по интервалу времени? Собственно для видео код такой:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <iframe width=100% height=100% src="video/video1.mp4" frameborder="0"    allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

скрипт просто

<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    spaceBetween: 30,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
    mousewheel: true,
    keyboard: true,
    autoplay: true,
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const swiperGallery = new Swiper(".swiper-gallery", {
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 1000,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
    }); 
    let videoSlide = $(".swiper-slide video");

    videoSlide.on("ended", function () {
        swiperGallery.autoplay.start();
    });
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]